# Custom Gate/Instruction with classical bits in Qiskit

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, programming

In Qiskit, I need to define a custom gate or instruction that, once decomposed, turns into a series of basis gates, including measurements and classically controlled gates (this is the part that I can't get around).

I already tried using `QuantumCircuit.to_gate()`, but it does not work, maybe there is a way to it with the `Instruction` class?

**Edit 1**

I tried to do something like this:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister

def mygate():
    qr = QuantumRegister(4)
    cr1 = ClassicalRegister(1)
    cr2 = ClassicalRegister(1)
    qc = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr1, cr2, name='mygate')
    qc.measure(qr[0], cr1[0])
    qc.measure(qr[1], cr2[0])
    qc.x(qr[-2]).c_if(cr1, 1)
    qc.x(qr[-1]).c_if(cr2, 1)

    return qc.to_instruction()


big = QuantumCircuit(5, 4)
big.append(mygate(), range(4), range(2))
```

But it does not work.

```
qiskit.exceptions.QiskitError: 'Cannot convert condition in circuit with multiple classical registers to instruction'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand the question - do you want to algorithmically decompose a custom gate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert a circuit into an instruction, not a gate. A gate is assumed to be invertible, which is not the case if you have measurements and classical conditionals. Therefore, you need to create a custom instruction. Here is a short tutorial for that:

First, create a circuit will all your gates and instructions, with measurements and conditionals. This will be the custom instruction:

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.circuit.library import *

qr = QuantumRegister(2)
cr = ClassicalRegister(2)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr, name='my_inst')
circuit.h(qr[0])
circuit.cx(qr[0], qr[1])
circuit.measure(qr[1], cr[0])
circuit.append(XGate(), [qr[0]]).c_if(cr,2)
circuit.draw('text')
```

```
      ┌───┐         ┌───┐ 
q4_0: ┤ H ├──■──────┤ X ├─
      └───┘┌─┴─┐┌─┐ └─┬─┘ 
q4_1: ─────┤ X ├┤M├───┼───
           └───┘└╥┘┌──┴──┐
c4: 2/═══════════╩═╡ = 2 ╞
                 0 └─────┘
```

Then, you need to convert this circuit into an instruction:

```
my_inst = circuit.to_instruction()
```

This instruction can be append to another super circuit:

```
big_circuit = QuantumCircuit(5, 2)
big_circuit.h(range(5))
big_circuit.append(my_inst, range(2), range(2))
big_circuit.h(range(5))
big_circuit.draw('text')
```

```
     ┌───┐┌──────────┐┌───┐
q_0: ┤ H ├┤0         ├┤ H ├
     ├───┤│          │├───┤
q_1: ┤ H ├┤1         ├┤ H ├
     ├───┤│          │├───┤
q_2: ┤ H ├┤          ├┤ H ├
     ├───┤│          │├───┤
q_3: ┤ H ├┤  my_inst ├┤ H ├
     ├───┤│          │├───┤
q_4: ┤ H ├┤          ├┤ H ├
     └───┘│          │└───┘
c_0: ═════╡0         ╞═════
          │          │     
c_1: ═════╡1         ╞═════
          └──────────┘
```

There it is. If you decompose the instructions in this circuit, you will see the internal operations:

```
big_circuit.decompose().draw('text')
```

```
     ┌──────────┐   ┌───┐                         ┌───┐ ┌──────────┐
q_0: ┤ U2(0,pi) ├───┤ H ├──────■──────────────────┤ X ├─┤ U2(0,pi) ├
     ├──────────┤   └───┘    ┌─┴─┐┌─┐┌──────────┐ └─┬─┘ └──────────┘
q_1: ┤ U2(0,pi) ├────────────┤ X ├┤M├┤ U2(0,pi) ├───┼───────────────
     ├──────────┤┌──────────┐└───┘└╥┘└──────────┘   │               
q_2: ┤ U2(0,pi) ├┤ U2(0,pi) ├──────╫────────────────┼───────────────
     ├──────────┤├──────────┤      ║                │               
q_3: ┤ U2(0,pi) ├┤ U2(0,pi) ├──────╫────────────────┼───────────────
     ├──────────┤├──────────┤      ║                │               
q_4: ┤ U2(0,pi) ├┤ U2(0,pi) ├──────╫────────────────┼───────────────
     └──────────┘└──────────┘      ║             ┌──┴──┐            
c: 2/══════════════════════════════╩═════════════╡ = 2 ╞════════════
                                   0             └─────┘
```

If you want to decompose the circuit to a particular base, you can use the transpiler for that:

```
decomposed = transpile(big_circuit, basis_gates=['cx', 'u3'], optimization_level=0)
decomposed.draw('text', fold=-1)
```

```
     ┌───────────────┐┌───────────────┐                         ┌─────────────┐┌───────────────┐
q_0: ┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├──■──────────────────────┤ U3(pi,0,pi) ├┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├
     ├───────────────┤└───────────────┘┌─┴─┐┌─┐┌───────────────┐└──────┬──────┘└───────────────┘
q_1: ┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├─────────────────┤ X ├┤M├┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├───────┼────────────────────────
     ├───────────────┤┌───────────────┐└───┘└╥┘└───────────────┘       │                        
q_2: ┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├──────╫─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────
     ├───────────────┤├───────────────┤      ║                         │                        
q_3: ┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├──────╫─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────
     ├───────────────┤├───────────────┤      ║                         │                        
q_4: ┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├┤ U3(pi/2,0,pi) ├──────╫─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────
     └───────────────┘└───────────────┘      ║                      ┌──┴──┐                     
c: 2/════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╡ = 2 ╞═════════════════════
                                             0                      └─────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated my question with a slightly more complex example.

Comment: I see. The reason for *Edit 1* failer is because registers get flatten as part of the conversion. Because classical conditional depends on the names of classical registers, converting a circuit with more than a classical register creates a condition on a partial register, which is not supported. Therefore that situation is not allowed.

Comment: So there is no way to do it?

Comment: No. You can request the feature here https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/new/choose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to avoid the error you are getting as an `Instruction` can't handle multiple classical registers but here is a workaround.

```
def mygate():

  qr = QuantumRegister(4)
  cr1 = ClassicalRegister(1)
  cr2 = ClassicalRegister(1)

  qc = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr1, cr2, 
                      name='mygate')

  qc.measure(qr[0], cr1[0])
  qc.measure(qr[1], cr2[0])

  qc.x(qr[-2]).c_if(cr1, 1)
  qc.x(qr[-1]).c_if(cr2, 1)

  return qc



big = QuantumCircuit(5, 4)
big.compose(mygate(), 
            qubits=range(4), clbits=range(2), 
            inplace=True)
```

Comment: This will not create a custom instruction but will concatenate two circuits (`big` and `mygate`). The "encapsulation" of `mygate` happens at Python level, not at circuit level. Depending on your usecase, it's a possibility.